# Unity inconsistent memory profiling when running same scene

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, optimization, memory

I'm in the making of a 2D silhouette style game where I'm trying basically 2 setups:

- One where it consists **only** of sprites,
- One where it consists of a mix of **sprites** and **meshes with NO texture**.

Now, I'm experimenting with the two as I wish to want the scenes to take up the least memory.

I have these weird outcomes:

**SPRITE SETUP:**

- Total 280 MB, Textures 155.5 MB, Meshes 1.7 MB
- Total 249 MB, Textures 151 MB, Meshes 4.1 MB
- Total 279 MB, Textures 151.0 MB, Meshes 10.8 MB

**SPRITE & MESH SETUP:**

- Total 334.4 MB, Textures 188.2 MB, Meshes 1.8 MB
- Total 241 MB, Textures 148,0 MB, Meshes 2,3 MB
- Total 253.1 MB, Textures 157.7 MB, Meshes 4.2 MB
- Total 301.8 MB, Textures 157.7 MB, Meshes 8.4 MB
- Total 234.8 MB, Textures 145.3 MB, Meshes 1.9 MB

Now, I find these result strange because:

- It was checked on the **exact same scene** (the mesh setup had same amount of objects, just swapped the sprites for meshes) and the data is inconsistent, meaning there is about 100MB difference between the same mesh scene
- A scene of mostly mesh with **zero** textures uses more, or at least not less, textures than a sprite only scene??

By taking a look at the data above, I would require someone skilled to guide me through this. Shall I keep using those meshes or just go for sprites? What is really goind on here with this data?